# How do you run Visual Studio 2017 ASP.NET Core projects on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am looking to run a new .NET Core ASP.NET MVC project on a raspberry pi. I've followed various blogs such as [Scott Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunASPNET5Beta3OrGoLangOnARaspberryPi2.aspx)'s example here. I can run the sample projects included with the ASP.NET repository as well. However, the new projects generated with Visual Studio no longer include the `project.json` file which is required for the above tutorials and all other documentation I've been able to find.

Since these `project.json` files are no longer a thing in new .NET Core projects what are you supposed to do to compile and run your code on ARM processors? Presumably support for these platforms is not being dropped, and though support itself was never actually official to begin with, breaking it seems... off.

How do I build a Visual Studio 2017 project on a Raspberry PI? Kestrel is expecting a `project.json` file which does not exist and `dotnet` and other .NET Core tools aren't available. How do I build the `.csproj` file I do have?

Answer (score 2):

It's not officially supported yet, but you can have a look at

- https://carlos.mendible.com/2017/03/21/step-by-step-running-aspnet-core-on-raspberry-pi/
- http://www.devvy.nl/?p=170

Their approach is command-line based, but apart from the basic setup (creating the project from the template) and the deployment, you can still use VS2017 to edit the code.

Update: also have a look at https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2017/04/22/hosting-a-net-core-2-web-api-instance-on-the-raspberry-pi-3/ and and its source code at https://github.com/jeremylindsayni/RaspberryPi.WebApi/ for Powershell deployment and management scripts to Raspberry Pi (for windows IoT Core)